# How does prestashop display modules

Tags: php, prestashop

my quest is to swap position of 2 modules in left column.
I read that normally I should do this in administration panel -> live edit
The problem is that prestashop used by this web was little bit edited, some modules were deleted, so live edit does not work.

In code i found, that both modules are displayed from variable $HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN
Front controller assignes to this variable following data:

```
'HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN' => ($this->display_column_left ? Hook::exec('displayLeftColumn') : ''),
```

I found that this gets from database names of modules, unfortunatelly I do not have access into the database :-(
I was also searching in both modules and did not find that one includes another one.

So my question is: Does prestashop call modules in order they are set in database or is there any other way I can swap their positions.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `hook_module` table, you have a `position` field. This field is used to sort modules for a specific hook.

Comment: Can be done in BackOffice for most of the hooks including `displayLeftColumn`

Answer (score 2):

In your BackOffice go to `Modules` > `Positions`, search for `displayLeftColumn` and easily move the desired module up or down the hook